# How can I add an hover event to my nested div?

Tags: css, sass, hover

Take the following HTML structure and CSS

```
<div class="dropdown" onclick="addHover(this)">
    <div class="Rtooltip">More Options</div>
    <button class="table-menu dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
           <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">Add Project Personnel <span class="caret"></span></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Jared Kushner</a></li>
               <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Samuel Harris</a></li>
               <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">William Dafoe</a></li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Add All Personnel</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Add New Person</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>

.dropdown {
    &:hover {
        .Rtooltip {
            display: block;
        }
    }

    &.open {
        .Rtooltip {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}

// this doesn't work
.table-menu {
    &:hover {
        .Rtooltip {
            display: block;
        }
    }

}
```

The dropdown is triggered by the onclick event on the parent div. When you hover over the `.dropdown` the tooltip appears. I hide this tooltip when the dropdown is open utilizing an `.open` class on the dropdown. However, when you click an item on the dropdown the `.open` class is removed and for a split second the tooltip appears again because the `:hover` event is on dropdown.

I want to put the `:hover` event on the `button.table-menu` so it only shows up when the user hovers over the button, but when I move my css to trigger on hover over that button nothing happens. It appears that button.table-menu doesn't propagate to the top. What SASS do I need to write to make sure that the tooltip only shows up when the user hovers over `button.table-menu`?

Comment: Can you switch the `html` a little? Can the `.Rtooltip` be positioned after the `button`?

Comment: That doesn't solve anything. It's still relative to the container.

Comment: You need that change and some `css` or `scss` change too. Check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `css` you can select the next sibling but not the previous one, so, if you could change the `html` structure so you have `.Rtooltip` before the `button` this trick will work:

```html
<div class="dropdown" onclick="addHover(this)">
    <button class="table-menu dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="Rtooltip">More Options</div>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
           <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">Add Project Personnel <span class="caret"></span></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Jared Kushner</a></li>
               <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Samuel Harris</a></li>
               <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">William Dafoe</a></li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Add All Personnel</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Add New Person</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

So you could select the adjacent sibling combinator with the `+` selector:

```
.table-menu {
  &:hover {
    & + .Rtooltip {
        display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

More info about [adjacent sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#adjacent-sibling-combinators).

You can select the next sibling using `css` but not the previous one. So in the case you used, `.table-menu:hover .Rtooltip`; that way you were trying to select an element with the class `.Rtooltip` inside a hovered `.table-menu`. Using the adjacent sibling selector (and changing the sibling order so the tooltip comes after the button) `.table-menu:hover + .Rtooltip` will select an element with the class `.Rtooltip` that is the next sibling (comes after in the `html`) of a hovered `.table-menu`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Was my code not working because i had the Rtooltip before the button?

Comment: I guess I don't really understand why the adjacent selector here works?

Comment: I edited my answer with the explainations. Let me know if you need some more info. Glad i could help!

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense, but I have another problem now that seems like a weird bug. It's only happening in Chrome. When I hover over the button in the top corner the tooltip flickers. It's really weird I haven't seen anything like this before. Any ideas?

Comment: My mouse and the tooltip constantly flicker as I'm hovering over it in the top right corner.

Comment: Can you make a working fiddle so i can further assist?

Comment: Good, let me check it

Comment: Just add `z-index:1` to the tooltip and `z-index:2` to the button. That solves the issue.

Comment: It did! That's so bizarre. How did you figure it out? Where you just playing around with it and stumble upon that?

Comment: I just used the inspector, and "almost 20 years of my like" building websites haha